# making a 3D vector with two fixed lengths and one that can vary

Tags: c++, database

I wish to construct a 3D struct that will be made of an array with i=1..N sites, that in each i site there is a 2D vector, this vector has one finite dim k=1...L and on dim that changes during a simulation, starting at M=0 and  with push_back command L elements are updated.

I've added a figure explaining the structure, how can this thing can be written, note that it is important that I will be able to access this structure by index , say struct[i][j][k].

Note: this structure stores data of a simulation where there are N realizations , in each there are M time steps that can differ ( this happens during the run) in each realization and in each time step a lattice with L sites is updated.

[image]
I manage to do it for the 2D case but not 3D, what I have so far is:

```
array <vector <double>, N> Array;
array <array <vector <double>, N>, L> Brray;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    // calculate cal1 for 0'th index
    Array[i].push_back(i) = cal1;
    j=1;
    while (j<M)
    {
        // calculate cal1 
        Array[i].push_back(Array[i][j-1]+cal1);
        for (int k=0; k<L; j++)
        {
            // calculate cal2
            Brray[i][j][k] = cal2; // this is the line I have a problem
        }
        //perform cal3 that decides whether there will be another iteration
        if (cal3==1)
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puzzled as to why `struct[i][j][k]` is important. Would `struct(i, j, k)` not be just as good? `struct[i][j][k]` allows for someone to do dumb stuff like `struct[i][j].clear();`

Comment: I think `Brray[i][j].push_back(cal2)` is what you are after.

Comment: Or because you have L, ` Brray[i][j].resize(L);` right above `for (int k=0; k<L; j++)`. Hmmmm. Might want to check that j++ I don't see an increment of k anywhere.

Comment: And definitely look over @1201ProgramAlarm 's  answer again. I think he's right and you have the vector in the wrong spot. It looks like you have fixed length, variable length, fixed length, so you want the vector in the middle.

Comment: @user4581301, what you suggested does not work

Comment: @user4581301, the algorithm is fine in general, this can be obtained in matlab with no problem, there is some degisn fault here, I'm not a programmer, so I don't know what is a proper way to define such structures, but I wish to know since I'll be using these kind of things a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need :

- an array of fixed size N containing

  - a vector of variable size M containing

    - an array of const site L containing double values

You should use a `array<vector<array<double, L> >, N>`. But you need to allocate a new `array<double, L>` on each `i=0 ... N-1` iteration.

Your code would become (only `Brray` part edited):

```
array <vector <double>, N> Array;
array <vector <array<double, L> >, N> Brray;  // CHANGED
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    // calculate cal1 for 0'th index
    Array[i].push_back(i) = cal1;
    M = value; // value is different for every i
    j=1;
    while (j<M)
    {
        Brray[i].push_back(array<double, L>()); //ADDED: add a new array to vector
        // calculate cal1 
        Array[i].push_back(Array[i][j-1]+cal1);
        for (int k=0; k<L; j++)
        {
            // calculate cal2
            Brray[i][j][k] = cal2; // this is the line I have a problem - should work now
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

I could not test above code, but this one works correctly in C++11 mode (CLang):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    constexpr int N=5, L=8;
    std::array<std::vector<std::array<double, L> >, N> arr;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        const int M = 2*i;
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++) {
            arr[i].push_back(std::array<double, L>());
            for (int k=0; k< L; k++) {
                arr[i][j][k] = i+j+k;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        const int M = 2*i;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++) {
            std::cout << "\t" << j << " :";
            for (int k=0; k< L; k++) {
                std::cout << " " << arr[i][j][k];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this does not work, it produces an error: error C2275: 'std::tr1::array<_Ty,_Size>' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: If I'll be able to push_back the entire L size vector that would do the job perfectly

Comment: @jarhead: I've added a working code example. BTW, I had written `Brray[i].push_back(array<double, L>);` instead of `Brray[i].push_back(array<double, L>());` - it should explain the error...

Comment: I do not know M a priori to the loop

Comment: @jarhead: It is not a problem. As the array is allocated inside the loop, the `for j` loop could be a `j=0; while(condition) { ...; j+=1;}` one.

Comment: ok thanks,  I'm working on it now, I'll let you know the outcome

Comment: it works, and actually I can push_back the whole L size array into the vector

Answer (score 2):

`vector<vector<vector<double>>>`, or, since two of the dimensions are compile time constants, `array<vector<array<double, L>>, N>`.

**Edit**

To use this, you'd do something along these lines:

```
array<vector<array<double, L>>, N> dat;
```

This creates the initial array to hold all the data.  At the start of each realization, you already have an empty vector to hold the M results.  You'd either use

```
dat[i].resize(M);
```

if you know M at the start of your loop, or

```
dat[i].emplace_back();
```

to add one when you need to.  This will then give you your array with L sites, and you can populate it using indexing (`dat[i][j][k]`) or iterators.

Comment: I don't know M in every loop, it changes during the loop, depends on the calculations more or less time steps can be added, that is why I would like to update it with push_back

Comment: and what exacly is the "struct" in array<struct>, I use double variables there....

Comment: @jarhead `double` then.  It's pretty late where I am.

Comment: Ok, I also don't understand what the emplace_back if for, and can I insert the whole vector (1..L) as is with out a loop?

Comment: @jarhead `emplace_back` will construct the element in place, without having to create it then move/copy it.  The end result is the same as `push_back(array<double, L>())` but without the extra temporary.  You can also include parameters to the constructor as parameters to emplace_back.

Comment: Thanks for the help, first, I'm on the edge of making it work, I'm not a programmar though, so don't know some of the terms u r using, like a constructor.....so I did not get what you mean here....so with emplace_back I can insert the whole L size array? maybe you can add to your answer some example...?

Comment: @jarhead Since you seem to know `M` once you get within a realization, you can just use the `resize` call to allocate the array to use within that realization.

Comment: I don't know M, it can change( more push_backs) according to a calculation performed in the loop ( fixed the example)

Comment: @jarhead Whenever you need to add a new timestep, just use emplace_back or push_back.

Comment: yeah, I got that, but I can't seem to make it work.... maybe add some more guidelines in your answer...please....?